# Add dynamic color to each category item

Tags: plugins, posts

I'm trying to give custom color to each **category item**, But it gives only one style to all items.

I use this plugin for the colors:
'[Category Color](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-color/)'

My code as below,

```
<?php 
$category = get_the_category();
$the_category_id = $category[0]->cat_ID;

if(function_exists('rl_color'))
{
    $rl_category_color = rl_color($the_category_id);
}

$sep = '';
foreach ((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
    echo $sep . '<a href="' . get_category_link($cat->term_id) . '"  class="' . $cat->slug . '" title="View all posts in '. esc_attr($cat->name) . '" style="background:' . $rl_category_color . '">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a>';
    $sep = ', ';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the color for one category (*term* is more appropriate though)

```
$the_category_id = $category[0]->cat_ID;
```

instead of checking the ID and Color for each term, that's why it's applying the same to all.

Try this (untested):

```
<?php

    $categories = get_the_category();
    $sep = '';
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        $the_category_id = $cat->term_id;
        if(function_exists('rl_color')){
           $rl_category_color = rl_color($the_category_id);
        } else {
           $rl_category_color = '#000'; // maybe a default color?
        }
        echo $sep . '<a href="' . get_category_link($cat->term_id) . '"  class="' . $cat->slug . '" title="View all posts in '. esc_attr($cat->name) . '" style="background-color:' . $rl_category_color . '">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a>';
        $sep = ', ';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Woww THANKS The J! This works. And Thanks for the answers!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use "Term meta"?

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/how-to-use-term-meta-data-in-wordpress/

It's new in wordpress, like post meta, but with taxonomies (categories are taxonomies)

Answer (score -1):

Please try below plugin's or code

1. [colorful-categories](https://wordpress.org/plugins/colorful-categories/)
2. [how-to-assign-icons-images-and-colors-to-categories](https://wptavern.com/how-to-assign-icons-images-and-colors-to-categories-and-tags-in-the-wordpress-backend)
3. [Different-background-color-for-each-WordPress-category](http://ask.metafilter.com/251134/Different-background-color-for-each-WordPress-category)

May above links help you.

Comment: Can you also post crux of the code in addition to linking to external resources so that even if they are dead this answer weighs towards the solution.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do that, Yes and it will help upto long time.